# subsetting the data in stack bar

Tags: tableau-api

This is Shaunak Ponkshe, I had one requirement . I want to show numerator and denominator at correct scale. 
This scaling does not look possible as I have tried all the permutation on the same. 
My requirement is I had to show numerator and denominator  in stack bar and doing dual axis to show one calculated filed of result. 
I had attached the sample excel file snap shot your reference.
Awaiting for early reply.
[[sample demo] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Z5t.png

Answer (score -1):

According to the description given in the image, you want to create a combination chart with overlapping bars and a line. Check the given link to do the same.

http://vizwiz.blogspot.in/2011/08/tableau-tip-7-easy-steps-to-create.html